# QThread - problems with it (beginner)

Tags: c++, qt

I try to use QThread, but I can't do it :(
My sample thread:

```
#include "worker.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QDebug>
Worker::Worker() {}

Worker::~Worker() {
    qDebug() << "Worker ends.";
}

void Worker::run() {
    qDebug() << "Worker start.";
    sleep(2);
    emit finished();
}
```

And code on_btnStart_clicked():

```
Worker *worker = new Worker;
QThread *workerThread = new QThread(this);
connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(started()), worker, SLOT(start()));
connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(finished()), worker, SLOT(quit()));
worker->moveToThread(workerThread);
workerThread->start();
```

Worker starts, but never ends (if I close application, I get `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`. 
Another problem - how I can transfer data between thread and my application? I want to use QThread for QLabel (example: timer). I can't find any good tutorial that I can complile without problems. 
Anyone can help me?
And, if I can ask, how I can start thread like onCreate() for form? I want to create simple timer to count time of application running.
Regards

Comment: You connect `workerThread::started()` to `Worker::start()`, but in the code you provided there is `Worker::run()`, not `Worker::start()`. Check whether `connect` returns `true` or `false`.

Comment: _I can't find any good tutorial that I can complile without problems. Anyone can help me?_ Aren't <QTDIR>/examples/threads good enough? Also, you may want to read [Threading Basics](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html) blog post at qt-project.

Comment: @Paul - `Object::connect: No such slot QThread::run() in mainwindow.cpp:22`; at /usr/share/qt4/doc I don't find anything; at qt-project.org docs I find code like my, but It's didn't work; thanks for link, I'll try it

Comment: @Paul: `run` isn't a slot, `start` is and it essentially calls `run`.

Comment: QObject has its own timer, check QObject::startTimer, and QObject::timerEvent

Comment: _Object::connect: No such slot QThread::run() in mainwindow.cpp:22_ You should investigate this, every call to `connect` should return `true`. As for examples, you may download [Qt 4 sources](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/4.8/4.8.4/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.4.tar.gz), unpack them where you like and study examples and demos.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a read through [This](http://woboq.com/blog/qthread-you-were-not-doing-so-wrong.html) article.

> Look at the first code sample of the Qt 4.8 QThread documentation. It has many lines of boiler plate just to run some code in a thread. And the there is even a leak: the QThread is never going to quit and be destroyed.

The submitted patch has been accepted but the href link he forwards you to still shows the old code.

[This patch snippet](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#patch,sidebyside,45271,5,src/corelib/doc/snippets/code/src_corelib_thread_qthread.cpp) diff shows the valid approach on the right-side.

It shows both methods, sub-classing `QThread` and using `QObject->Worker`
You can use that as the sample to base your code on. Apply the approach that suit's your requirements as he mentions in the blog.